# Working out start of financial year

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

Our financial year starts at 1st of April of every year.  Therefore the current financial year is 1st of April 2011.

How do I get this date no matter what the current date is?

For example, today is 2011-06-24, how do I return 2011-04-30.

If today is 2012-02-05, I still need it to return 2011-04-30.  However, if today is 2012-07-06, it should return 2012-04-30.

So basically, the year of the financial date should not change to the current year until the first of May is reached.

i.e. some examples

```
2011-03-05 = 2010-04-30
2011-04-06 = 2011-04-30
2010-01-15 = 2009-04-30
2015-09-01 = 2015-04-30
2020-12-25 = 2020-04-30
2021-02-26 = 2020-04-30
```

Comment: Just check for the current date, if its less than 1 April, then the year will be previous year, else the year will be current year.

Comment: edited my answer, as you edit the question with some data, just use the methods I wrote (I hope in VB is the exact translation of C#... I'm a C# fellow)

Comment: Please will you explain why you ask for the 1st April and your examples all return 30th April?  What is the significance of the end of the first calendar month of the financial year?

Comment: Sorry, should have been first of may.

Comment: Is the example `2011-04-06 = 2011-04-30` correct? In this case the start of the current fiscal year is in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the:

```
  Dim dateTime__1 As New DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-4).Year, 4, 30)
```

Comment: it's always best to wrap it up in a shared/static method so it can be called anytime we need instead having to mention all that every time :)

Comment: How about setting this once at the starting, then calling `dateTime__1` anything it is needed?

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in function, however it's easy to build yourself:

- Get the current date
- If it's april or later, use the year and set month and day to april 1st
- If it's before april, use the year before, again april 1st.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple use a static method:

```
public static GetStartOfFinancialYear() {

    DateTime startOfYear = new DateTime( Datetime.UtcNow.Year, 4, 30 );
    return 
        DateTime.UtcNow < startOfYear ? 
            startOfYear.AddYears(-1) : startOfYear;

}
```

in VB

```
public shared Function GetStartOfFinancialYear() As DateTime

    Dim startOfYear As New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 30)

    If DateTime.UtcNow < startOfYear Then
        return startOfYear.AddYears(-1) 
    Else
        return startOfYear
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I was going to answer the same way, but this is not what is asked - for 3/12/2012 it should return 4/1/2011 and for 5/12/2012 it should return 4/1/2012

Comment: I didnt got the question right, he edit it while I was answering it.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake, it should have been 30 instead of 1, but I can see that I just need to change the 1 in your example to 30.

Answer (score 0):

The [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) includes the class **Year** with support of fiscal time periods.

You can define a fiscal time calendar with a custom year base month. The following sample uses October as the start of the fiscal year:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class FiscalTimeCalendar : TimeCalendar
{
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  public FiscalTimeCalendar() :
    base( new TimeCalendarConfig
      {
        YearBaseMonth = YearMonth.October,  //  October year base month
        YearWeekType = YearWeekType.Iso8601, // ISO 8601 week numbering
        YearType = YearType.FiscalYear// treat years as fiscal years
      } )
  {
  } // FiscalTimeCalendar
} // class FiscalTimeCalendar
```

And that's the usage:
Collapse

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void FiscalYearSample()
{
  FiscalTimeCalendar calendar = new FiscalTimeCalendar(); // use fiscal periods

  DateTime moment1 = new DateTime( 2006, 9, 30 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Fiscal Year of {0}: {1}", moment1.ToShortDateString(),
                     new Year( moment1, calendar ).YearName );
  // > Fiscal Year of 30.09.2006: FY2005
  Console.WriteLine( "Fiscal Quarter of {0}: {1}", moment1.ToShortDateString(),
                     new Quarter( moment1, calendar ).QuarterOfYearName );
  // > Fiscal Quarter of 30.09.2006: FQ4 2005

  DateTime moment2 = new DateTime( 2006, 10, 1 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Fiscal Year of {0}: {1}", moment2.ToShortDateString(),
                     new Year( moment2, calendar ).YearName );
  // > Fiscal Year of 01.10.2006: FY2006
  Console.WriteLine( "Fiscal Quarter of {0}: {1}", moment1.ToShortDateString(),
                     new Quarter( moment2, calendar ).QuarterOfYearName );
  // > Fiscal Quarter of 30.09.2006: FQ1 2006
} // FiscalYearSample
```

The library includes also the classes **Halfyear** and **Quarter** with support of fiscal time periods.